# Reading Standard Output from a Command Line process without newline

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I'm writing a C# GUI Wrapper that wraps around an executable (which I **CAN NOT** modify because I do not have the source code). The problem I'm facing appears to be related to the fact the executable output does not end with a 'newline' character.

Instead, the .exe starts work and expects user input (s=status, q=quit, etc..).

I've spent a lot of time researching various ways to read StdOut, one with Asynchronous reads and listening for events, and the other method was with separate threads polling StdOut and StdErr and raising events to the UI thread which is updating the textbox.

Unfortunately, neither of these two methods seem to work since in both cases - the process does not raise events until the last line of output (one which has no 'newline' at the end), which is only displayed when the application closes.

Also, I can't seem to be able to send commands to it either by writing to it's StandardInput. I've followed the typical advice of disabling ShellExecute, Redirecting Input, etc...

I tried sending both a string, a char, a hex-representation of a char both as Write() and WriteLine(), and neither of those appear to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried piping stdout of the subprocess into an app, that uses stdin as a binary unbuffered stream?

Comment: Eugen, 
I have not tried that yet. Are you suggesting I create an 'app3' that the output of APP2 is piped into, and then communicate between app3 and app1 (the wrapper) any way I want to? 


Also, I think the more immediate problem is the StandardInput that I dedicated the last two paragraphs to.

Comment: Same thing for Input: Another Apps output as unbuffered binary Stream, piped into the target app. Backround: I had zo exactly that some years ago (Not C#, but Free Pascal)

Comment: Eugen, the "target app" already accepts input and a C# process has a StandardInput stream you're supposed to be writing to. **When I try to do it with "cmd.exe" and send "dir" to it's STDin, everything works fine.**

Comment: Sorry to be inexact: The streams you aquire when redirecting StdIn and StdOut via a process created inside C# are line-buffered. StdIn and StdOut need NOT be. So piping is not the same thing as redirecting. I'll follow up with code tomorrow.

Comment: If the app responds to single keystrokes then you have a strong hint that it is not reading from stdin.